# React Image Lightbox with sliding animation on navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building an Image Lightbox with React / Redux with a very similar design implementation as [this](https://codepen.io/neptunian/pen/Oxraod).

Basically in the ImageGrid and Lightbox components, I have:

ImageGrid.jsx

```
render() { 
  ...
  IMAGES.map((image, index) => {
    <Image onClick={() => this.props.openLightbox(index)} />
  })
  {this.props.showLightbox && <Lightbox images={IMAGES} />}
}
```

Lightbox.jsx

```
render() {
  <div>
    <img src={this.props.images[this.props.lightbox.index]} />
  </div>
}
```

This is a very stripped down version of the code but it should illustrate the important parts of the implementation. To implement Next / Previous photo functionality is trivial, I would just have to change the current photo index. However, for my `Lightbox`, I want to be able to navigate to the next / prev photo with a sliding animation.

For example, if I click Next, the current photo should slide left and the new photo slides in from the right side.

One idea I have is to render the Lightbox as a carousel of ALL the images and then simply `translate` the carousel on Prev / Next. But I do not want to do that in case the number of images is very large.

My intuition is to use `React.cloneElement` to create the Previous or Next photo and then animate them but I'm having issues wrapping my head around how I would do that within the React ecosystem. Especially because currently my `render` function for the `Lightbox` just has one `img`